# How to use multiple variables from regular expression extractor in HTTP sampler

Tags: jmeter

I have the following json response from HTTP sampler

{
url: "https://example.com/ir/rest/wsVerRest/getFile?filePath=/data/IR/data/IR_Org/user.mail@abc.com/testSample1_testSample2/testSample1_20151201214307897/outputs/CnvActor-00/testCoverage1.seg",
},

{
       url: "https://example.com/ir/rest/wsVerRest/getFile?filePath=/data/IR/data/IR_Org/user.mail@abc.com/testSample1_testSample2/testSample1_20151201214307897/outputs/CnvActor-00/testCoverage2.seg",}...{testCoverageN.seg}

From these I have to construct another htto sampler by using the server(ie xyz.itw),url(/ir/rest/wsVerRest/getFile),keyparam(filePath),value(/data/IR/data/IR_Org/user.mail@abc.com/testSample1_testSample2/testSample1_20151201214307897/outputs/CnvActor-00/testCoverage2.seg)

How to get these values using regular expression extractor and use in another sampler.

At present I can use regex to get those values.but don't know how to use in another http sampler.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> At present I can use regex to get those values.but don't know how to
>   use in another http sampler.Please help.Thanks

If you are able to get these values via Reg Expression extractor then it will not be a problem for you. When you use Regular expression extractor then the value are stored in "Reference Name" that you mentioned in your Extractor.

Lets say, your reference names were like below:

```
ServerValue
UrlValue
KeyParamValue
and so on..
```

you can simply use them like this in your intended HTTP sampler..

```
${ServerValue}${UrlValue}${KeyParamValue}
```